# Can't add a new blank page in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms

I have an already build Xamarin App but now I want to add the Sign Up / Login Page at the Start. When I open the App, first It open a Sign up Page.

I add a Blank Page with Title "Welcome to App" and Add a Button, but the Button doesn't work and only It works when it uses the Navigation of Other Pages, why? and how to add a sign up form on blank page?

[**IMAGE: It now looks like this.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uRSU.jpg)

I want to remove these Credentials, Accounts e.t.c from the top and just have an blank page of Sign Up.

Here is the Code, I hope it helps you to understand it better. If you need anything else, kindly ask for it.

Thanks :)

**UPDATE: [@Jason Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61140167/cant-add-a-new-blank-page-in-xamarin#comment108162862_61140167) : I removed Login Code from MainPage.xml, now the Navigation Tabs are no longer there but now the Button isn't working (when I click on it, nothing happens).**

[image]

**LoginPage.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Osma.Mobile.App.Converters;assembly=Osma.Mobile.App"
    xmlns:behaviours="clr-namespace:Osma.Mobile.App.Behaviors;assembly=Osma.Mobile.App"
    xmlns:components="clr-namespace:Osma.Mobile.App.Views.Components;assembly=Osma.Mobile.App"
    x:Class="Osma.Mobile.App.Views.Login.LoginPage"
    Title="Login"
    xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
    ios:Page.LargeTitleDisplay="Always"
>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to App"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            <Button Text="Enter"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                Command="{Binding ButtonClickedCommand}"
                />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**LoginPage.xml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Osma.Mobile.App.Views.Login
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**LoginViewMode.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Acr.UserDialogs;
using Hyperledger.Aries.Contracts;
using Hyperledger.Aries.Features.DidExchange;
using Hyperledger.Aries.Utils;
using Osma.Mobile.App.Events;
using Osma.Mobile.App.Extensions;
using Osma.Mobile.App.Services;
using Osma.Mobile.App.Services.Interfaces;
using ReactiveUI;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Osma.Mobile.App.ViewModels.Credentials;

namespace Osma.Mobile.App.ViewModels.Login
{
    public class LoginViewModel : ABaseViewModel
    {
        private readonly ICustomAgentContextProvider _agentContextProvider;
        private readonly IConnectionService _connectionService;

        public LoginViewModel(
            IUserDialogs userDialogs,
            INavigationService navigationService,
            ICustomAgentContextProvider agentContextProvider,
            IConnectionService defaultConnectionService) :
            base("Login", userDialogs, navigationService)
        {
            _agentContextProvider = agentContextProvider;
            _connectionService = defaultConnectionService;
        }

        public ICommand ButtonClickedCommand => new Command(async () => await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync<CredentialsViewModel>());
    }
}
```

**App.xaml.css**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Autofac;
using Microsoft.AppCenter;
using Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics;
using Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes;
using Osma.Mobile.App.Services.Interfaces;
using Osma.Mobile.App.Utilities;
using Osma.Mobile.App.ViewModels;
using Osma.Mobile.App.ViewModels.Login;
using Osma.Mobile.App.ViewModels.Account;
using Osma.Mobile.App.ViewModels.Connections;
using Osma.Mobile.App.ViewModels.CreateInvitation;
using Osma.Mobile.App.ViewModels.Credentials;
using Osma.Mobile.App.Views;
using Osma.Mobile.App.Views.Login;
using Osma.Mobile.App.Views.Account;
using Osma.Mobile.App.Views.Connections;
using Osma.Mobile.App.Views.CreateInvitation;
using Osma.Mobile.App.Views.Credentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Internals;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using LoginPage = Osma.Mobile.App.Views.Login.LoginPage;

[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace Osma.Mobile.App
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public new static App Current => Application.Current as App;
        public Palette Colors;

        private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
        private readonly ICustomAgentContextProvider _contextProvider;

        public App(IContainer container)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new LoginPage();

            Colors.Init();
            _navigationService = container.Resolve<INavigationService>();
            _contextProvider = container.Resolve<ICustomAgentContextProvider>();

            InitializeTask = Initialize();
        }

        Task InitializeTask;
        private async Task Initialize()
        {
            //Pages
            _navigationService.AddPageViewModelBinding<MainViewModel, MainPage>();
            _navigationService.AddPageViewModelBinding<LoginViewModel, LoginPage>();
            _navigationService.AddPageViewModelBinding<ConnectionsViewModel, ConnectionsPage>();
            _navigationService.AddPageViewModelBinding<ConnectionViewModel, ConnectionPage>();
            _navigationService.AddPageViewModelBinding<RegisterViewModel, RegisterPage>();
            _navigationService.AddPageViewModelBinding<AcceptInviteViewModel, AcceptInvitePage>();
            _navigationService.AddPageViewModelBinding<CredentialsViewModel, CredentialsPage>();
            _navigationService.AddPageViewModelBinding<CredentialViewModel, CredentialPage>();
            _navigationService.AddPageViewModelBinding<AccountViewModel, AccountPage>();
            _navigationService.AddPageViewModelBinding<CreateInvitationViewModel, CreateInvitationPage>();

            if (_contextProvider.AgentExists())
            {
                await _navigationService.NavigateToAsync<LoginViewModel>();
            }
            else
            {
                await _navigationService.NavigateToAsync<LoginViewModel>();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            #if !DEBUG 
                AppCenter.Start("ios=" + AppConstant.IosAnalyticsKey + ";" +
                                "android=" + AppConstant.AndroidAnalyticsKey + ";",
                        typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
            #endif
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:connections="clr-namespace:Osma.Mobile.App.Views.Connections;assembly=Osma.Mobile.App"
    xmlns:credentials="clr-namespace:Osma.Mobile.App.Views.Credentials;assembly=Osma.Mobile.App"
    xmlns:account="clr-namespace:Osma.Mobile.App.Views.Account;assembly=Osma.Mobile.App"
    xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
    x:Class="Osma.Mobile.App.Views.MainPage"
    CurrentPageChanged="CurrentPageChanged"
    Appearing="Appearing"
>
    <connections:ConnectionsPage
        Icon="connection_icon.png"
        ios:NavigationPage.PrefersLargeTitles="true"
        BindingContext="{Binding Connections}">
    </connections:ConnectionsPage>
    <credentials:CredentialsPage
        Icon="credentials_icon.png"
        ios:NavigationPage.PrefersLargeTitles="true"
        BindingContext="{Binding Credentials}">
    </credentials:CredentialsPage>
    <account:AccountPage
        Icon="account_icon.png"
        ios:NavigationPage.PrefersLargeTitles="true"
        BindingContext="{Binding Account}">
    </account:AccountPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Acr.UserDialogs;
using Osma.Mobile.App.Services.Interfaces;
using Osma.Mobile.App.ViewModels.Login;
using Osma.Mobile.App.ViewModels.Account;
using Osma.Mobile.App.ViewModels.Connections;
using Osma.Mobile.App.ViewModels.CreateInvitation;
using Osma.Mobile.App.ViewModels.Credentials;
using ReactiveUI;

namespace Osma.Mobile.App.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : ABaseViewModel
    {
        public MainViewModel(
            IUserDialogs userDialogs,
            INavigationService navigationService,
            LoginViewModel loginViewModel,
            ConnectionsViewModel connectionsViewModel,
            CredentialsViewModel credentialsViewModel,
            AccountViewModel accountViewModel,
            CreateInvitationViewModel createInvitationViewModel)
            : base(
                nameof(MainViewModel),
                userDialogs,
                navigationService
        )
        {
            Login = loginViewModel;
            Connections = connectionsViewModel;
            Credentials = credentialsViewModel;
            Account = accountViewModel;
            CreateInvitation = createInvitationViewModel;
        }

        public override async Task InitializeAsync(object navigationData)
        {
            await Login.InitializeAsync(null);
            await Connections.InitializeAsync(null);
            await Credentials.InitializeAsync(null);
            await Account.InitializeAsync(null);
            await CreateInvitation.InitializeAsync(null);
            await base.InitializeAsync(navigationData);
        }

        #region Bindable Properties
        private LoginViewModel _login;
        public LoginViewModel Login
        {
            get => _login;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _login, value);
        }

        private ConnectionsViewModel _connections;
        public ConnectionsViewModel Connections
        {
            get => _connections;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _connections, value);
        }

        private CredentialsViewModel _credentials;
        public CredentialsViewModel Credentials
        {
            get => _credentials;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _credentials, value);
        }

        private AccountViewModel _account;
        public AccountViewModel Account
        {
            get => _account;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _account, value);
        }

        private CreateInvitationViewModel _createInvitation;
        public CreateInvitationViewModel CreateInvitation
        {
            get => _createInvitation;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _createInvitation, value);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: if you don't want the tabs showing on the LoginPage, then remove LoginPage from the tabbed page, and on app startup assign `MainPage = new LoginPage();` in `App.xaml.cs`

Comment: @jason, using LoginPage = Osma.Mobile.App.Views.Login.LoginPage;                 
   public App(IContainer container)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new LoginPage();

Comment: @Jason, kindly have a look at App.xml.cs, I already add LoginPage() there!

Comment: @Jason and from which pages, I should remove the code?

Comment: @Jason, I remove Login code from MainPage.xml, now when App starts it doesn't even show up the Login Page, opened the Credential Page, why?

Comment: @Jason, I removed Login Code from MainPage.xml, now the Navigation Tabs are no longer there but now the Button isn't working (when I click on it, nothing happens). -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAJpw.jpg

Comment: I don't see anything in your LoginPage that instantiates the LoginViewModel

Comment: public ICommand ButtonClickedCommand => new Command(async () => await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync<CredentialsViewModel>()); in LoginViewMode.cs

Comment: that has nothing to do with my comment.  Are you using some MVVM library?

Comment: Yes, I'm using MVVM!

Comment: The code is from this Open Source Repo: https://github.com/hyperledger/aries-mobileagent-xamarin

Comment: I've never heard of that library and have no idea what it does or how it works.  It would have been incredibly helpful if you had mentioned that you were relying on some obscure third party library in your original question.

Comment: This Repo is not an MVVM Library, it's Open Source Project (a mobile application), and it is built on top of Xamarin. and I think MVVM is architectural pattern.

Comment: and sorry if I wasn't clear, I'm using MVVM not MVVM library and my problem is why button isn't working when the Navigation Bar from the top is gone, while it works when it show up?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see that you have a NavigationPage instance anywhere, so how does your NavigationService works?

NavigationService usually inserts a page to a stack of pages on a NaviagtionPage instance.

I see in App.xaml.cs you make the LoginPage your main page, but where do you switch it to a NavigationPage, or to your TabbedPage?

You need to check what your MainPage should really be.

Comment: read the conversation I had with @jason in a comment section, "I removed Login Code from MainPage.xml, now the Navigation Tabs are no longer there but now the Button isn't working (when I click on it, nothing happens). -> i.stack.imgur.com/EAJpw.jpg "

Comment: first it looks like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uRSU.jpg), but the button was working. Now it looks like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAJpw.jpg), and now button isn't working, why?

Comment: Again, TabbedPage and your LoginPage are not inheriting NaviagtionPage, and since these were your MainPage, I don't see what NavigationService does.
I think you are missing a NavigationPage instance somewhere for it all to work.